# Connecting more elements to Raspberry pi servo hat

Tags: gpio, servo

I have bought [this](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-16-channel-pwm-servo-hat-for-raspberry-pi/connecting-servos) rpi servo hat to control some servos. But I'm wondering if I still can add elements like leds or like a movement sensor to the GPIO. At all examples I can see that the GPIO is soldered to the hat, and it has just servos attached to it. GPIO pins are used just like a bridge.

So, can I add more elements like leds and input sensors to the GPIO using its library and some servos to the headers using the hat's library?

Comment: The line of holes extending from "SDA" to "#21" are (most of) the GPIO pins broken out into a row, minus the powers and grounds which look to be on the right hand side.  So it can't be that you aren't suppose to use them.  I2C and SPI are multiplex buses; WRT the former you can use `i2cdetect` to find out which, if any addresses are actually used by the hat.

Comment: @goldilocks Thank you for commenting. It looks like you are right, I will give it a try. I miss some more extended documentation for the hat.